# Make the text of textblock depend on its variable

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have 9 textblocks ,each displays a variable

```
int blockNum1,blockNum2,blockNum3, ...;
textblock1.Text = blockNum1.ToString();
textblock2.Text = blockNum2.ToString();
textblock3.Text = blockNum3.ToString();
...
```

So how can i change the color of number displayed on each "textblock" depend on its blockNum variable

```
blockNum4 = 1 -> textblock4 display red text + number "1",
blockNum4 = 2 -> textblock4 display yellow text + number "2"  etc.
```

btw, sorry for my bad english :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your goal you can also make your text color (Foreground property) dependant on Text (string). For this purpose you will need to use a converter and bind Foreground to Text. The very simple example can look like this:

Converter:

```
public class NumberToColor : IValueConverter
{
    private SolidColorBrush[] tableOfColors = new SolidColorBrush[] 
    {
        new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow), // Number = 1
        new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)     // Number = 2
    };

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {            
        if (value == null) return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        else return tableOfColors[int.Parse((string)value) - 1];
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Array.FindIndex(tableOfColors, brush => brush == (SolidColorBrush)value);
    }
}
```

As you can see I've defined a `tableOfColors` and then depending on parsed text I change the Foreground. Note that it can also be done in many different ways - taking color from RGB and so on. It depends on your needs.

Then in XAML you can use it like this:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <app:NumberToColor x:Key="myConv" xmlns:app="clr-namespace:Example"/>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <TextBlock Name="myText" Text="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource myConv}}"/>
</Grid>
```

The color will automatically changed with Text. Note that this is a very simple example and needs many improvements (especially many check ups while parsing the Text), but hopefully it will help you to solve the problem. Other advantage is that this implementation doesn't need `blockNum1` value. The [complete sample code you can download here](http://1drv.ms/1jhY9D4). Good luck.

Comment: you can make your array static and initialize it in a static constructor. Also, be sure to `Freeze()` those `SolidColorBrush`es. I've had some issues when running multiple threads in a program where they throw exceptions because of wrong thread (can't remember which one. Let me know if you'd like me to double check it)

Comment: @Default You are right. But this is a Windows Phone app and I guess that Converter would be run on single UI thread. I wanted also to show the OP simple example. Nevertheless thank you for remarks.

Answer (score 0):

you can call a method like this which checks the number in text and then sets the color accordingly

```
if(blockNum1.ToString().Trim() == '1')
{
  textblock1.Foreground = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
  textblock1.Text=blockNum1.ToString();
}
```